# Benchmarking HTTPS on Windows localhost

Tags: https, bombardier

I'm trying to benchmark HTTP and HTTPS on a Windows machine, just using a local server.

[Bombardier](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/codesenberg/bombardier) builds and runs fine on Windows, and works for benchmarking a local HTTP server; I've tried it on a server written in Go, and also Java `com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer`, and it worked both times.

When I try it with an instance of `com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpsServer` it fails:

```
C:\bombardier-master>bombardier.exe --insecure https://localhost
Bombarding https://localhost for 10s using 125 connection(s)
[==========================================================================================================================================================================================================] 10s
Done!
Statistics        Avg      Stdev        Max
  Reqs/sec        74.64      73.69     703.25
  Latency         1.57s   566.72ms      2.40s
  HTTP codes:
    1xx - 0, 2xx - 0, 3xx - 0, 4xx - 0, 5xx - 0
    others - 855
  Errors:
    tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority - 541
    tls handshake timed out - 205
    dial tcp [::1]:443: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. - 109
  Throughput:    81.41KB/s
```

On the face of it, the problem is about certificate verification, which makes sense because I'm just using a locally generated key store, a self-signed certificate. Chrome reflects this by popping up that notice saying this is insecure, and requiring you to confirm that you want to proceed anyway.

But I'm not trying to verify certificates. I'm just trying to run a benchmark. As I understood it, the `--insecure` option to Bombardier should deal with that:

```
-k, --insecure              Controls whether a client verifies the server's
                            certificate chain and host name
```

But as shown above, I used it here, and it made no difference.

What am I missing? Should I be using a different option, or a different tool?